# How to select from a sum the terms containing minus?

Tags: filtering, pure-function

In a sum

```
y = \[Beta] x v - \[Mu] y z - \[Gamma] y;
```

I would like to extract the terms which contain a minus, i.e.  - [Mu] y z and - [Gamma] y

I can test when a term contains a minus via

```
ContainsNone[List @@ y1[[2]], {-1}]
```

Then I would like a pure function test like

```
test = ContainsNone[#, {-1}] &
Select[List @@ y1, test]
```

But the pure function is not well written

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separating positive and negative terms in an algebraic expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184188/separating-positive-and-negative-terms-in-an-algebraic-expression) Briefly, you are probably looking for ``Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ``.

Comment: Maybe `test=MatchQ[#,(_?Negative)*(_:1)]&`.

Comment: Yes, it works :)

Comment: Also, `negTerms[expr_, lvl_ : 1] := Cases[expr, Times[-1, __] | _?Negative, lvl]`

Comment: Thanks, I believe I managed to decipher this syntax, Times[-1, __] | _?Negative is a Pattern of two Alternatives. For the first syntax, *(_:1) seems more mysterious :)